# Let f(x) be a non negative continuous function on R such that $f(x) +f(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$ then calculate ........

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Problem :

Let f(x) be a non negative continuous function on R such that $f(x) +f(x+\frac{1}{3})=5$

then calculate the value of the integral $\int^{1200}_0 f(x) dx$

My approach :

Given that :  $f(x) +f(x+\frac{1}{3})=5.....(1) $

We replace x with $x +\frac{1}{3}$ so we get the given equation as :

$f(x+\frac{1}{3})+f(x+\frac{2}{3}).....(2)$

Now subtracting (1) from (2) we get :

$f(x+\frac{2}{3}) = f(x) $

$\Rightarrow f(x) $ is function with period $\frac{2}{3}$

Now how to move further please help on how the period of this function will impact the limit of integration. Thanks.

Comment: Well then the integral over an interval of size $M(2/3)$ (where $M$ is an integer) is $M$ times the integral over its period.  So $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{M(2/3)}\int_{0}^{M(2/3)} f(t)dt = \frac{1}{2/3}\int_0^{2/3} f(x)dx$.  You can compute an approximation for $\int_0^t f(x)dx$ for large $t$.

Comment: f is none negative so that its integral over 2 periods is twice the integral over one period. Now integrate your original functional equation over one period.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note
$$\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f(x)dx= \int_0^{1/3}f(x+\frac{1}{3})dx$$
and hence
$$ \int_0^{1/3}f(x)dx+\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/3}(f(x)+f(x+\frac{1}{3}))dx=\frac{5}{3}.$$
Then write
$$\int_0^{1200}f(x)dx=\int_0^{1/3}f(x)dx+\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f(x)dx+\cdots$$
and you will get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

$\int_0 ^{1200}f=\int_0 ^{\frac{2}{3}}f+\int_{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{4}{3}}f+...$

$\int _{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{4}{3}}f(x)=\int_0 ^{\frac{2}{3}}f(x)$

$\int _0^ {1200} f=800\times \int _0^{\frac{2}{3}}f$

$\int _0^{\frac{2}{3}}f=\int _0^{\frac{1}{3}}f+\int _{\frac{2}{3}}^{\frac{4}{3}}f$

Let $y=x-{\frac{1}{3}} \implies dy=dx$
 As $x={\frac{2}{3}} y={\frac{1}{3}};x={\frac{1}{3}}y=0$

$=\int _0^{\frac{1}{3}}f(y)dy+\int _0^{\frac{1}{3}}f(y+\frac{1}{3})dy$

$=\int _0^\frac{1}{3}5dy$